# Spring boot and Spring Data JPA @Transactional Not Working

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have created a sample `SpringBoot` project and using `JPA` Repository for persisting simple Greeting object in database (`Greeting Id` and Greeting Text). I have added `@Transactional` annotaion to `createGreeting()` method in service class `GreetingServiceImpl` and throwing a `RuntimeException` after Greeting record is persisted in database. I except the Greeting record be rolledback in the database. But the record still exists in the databse. Code given below. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringBootDataWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDataWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ServletInitializer**

```
 public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(SpringBootDataWebApplication.class);
        }

    }
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
public class Greeting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
    @RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> createGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting greeting) throws Exception {
        Greeting greetingCreated = greetingService.createGreeting(greeting);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(greetingCreated, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingRepository greetingRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public Greeting createGreeting(Greeting greeting) {
        if (greeting.getId() != null)
            return null;
        Greeting greetingCreated = greetingRepository.save(greeting);
        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Roll me back!");
        }
        return greetingCreated;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface GreetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Greeting, Long> {

}
```

**POM File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sam</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootDataWeb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Spring Data</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1465094495762,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "message": "Roll me back!",
  "path": "/SpringBootDataWeb/api/greetings"
}
```

Comment: I've tested your setup and it's working like you expect - transaction is rolled back, nothing is saved into DB. Perhaps you should create a [mcve] in a form of a github project.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use MySQL with [MyISAM engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)? I'm asking because it doesn't support transactions.

Comment: Yes Roman, I am using MySQL.

Comment: But which engine do you use for your `Greeting` table: MyISAM or InnoDB or some other?

Comment: Its default engine. And I guess its Innodb.

Comment: Roman, I see problem with SpringBoot Jar application and SpringBoot War application. Transaction rollback is working fine in application which has packaging as Jar and using inbuilt Tomcat server.

Comment: When I create SpringBoot application as war packaging and Use Jboss as server, transaction is not getting rolledback. Is there anything I have to tweet in Jboss AS.

Comment: use the @transient annotation on any object/properties of an object if you dont want that info to be saved to the db

Answer (score 0):

Ideally roll back is done while unit/integration testing. And during those scenarios, the annotation `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)` is used over the class where test cases are written.

Can you try this out on your service class.

Comment: @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) annotation is deprecated SriKanta.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to have in mind:

- The `@Repository` annotation is not necesary since your repository interface already extends from `JpaRepository`.
- Your service implementation is lacking (or at least is not in the example above) a `@Service` annotation, so the `@Autowired` in the controller should not work (I assume you have it in the interface? Since you don't have bean related exceptions).
- The `@Transactional` on the method level is correct, although by default it sets `readOnly=false`, so you don't need to specify it again

What I'm thinking is that your Greeting entity may not be correctly mapped, but still is hard to guess with the error message displayed. Could you give more information about the error stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for the points. Please find the code at below github url . I have @service Annotation declared in code, but I missed while copy paste.     https://github.com/SandeepGoud0612/SpringBootDataWeb.git

Comment: By the way, I have created Web Application Project(War Packaging). I am using JBoss Wildfly and Mysql.

Answer (score -1):

at high-level `JpaTransactionManager` is bound to `greetingRepository.save(greeting)`.

If there any any exception occurred inside the save method would do a rollback, `JpaTransactionManager` will execute `commit` if there is no exception during `save` and `TransactionStatus` will be set to `completed`.

So post commit if there is any exception occurred in application code not  bound to `JpaTransactionManager` is an application exception.

Comment: But I want to manage transaction from Service class. How can I achieve that?